# How to pull values from this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm rather new to PHP and I'm trying to pull specific values from an array

My code is `$zc1 = DB::query('select lat, lon from zips where zip_code=?', $zip1);`

When I `return print_r($zc1);` I get the following

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 38.296199798584 [lon] => -77.485298156738 ) )

My question is how do I get the values of "lat" and "lon"?

I'm using the PHP framework Laravel by the way.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: See [array traversal](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=&json=%5B%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%22lat%22+%3A+38.296199798584%2C%0D%0A+++++++++%22lon%22+%3A+-77.485298156738%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%5D)

Answer (score 2):

This is so basic, that if you don't know this you should probably read a book or two on PHP.

Having said that, here's how:

```
$lat = $zc1[0]->lat;
$lon = $zc1[0]->lon;
```